# angularjs routes parameters issue

Tags: angularjs, url, parameters

How I can get parameter from such url in angularjs controller:

```
http://localhost:53315/Employee/{parameter}#/info
```

Here's my angularjs code:

```
    $routeProvider
 .when('/info', {
            controller: 'UserCtrl',
            templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + 'info.html'
        });
.controller('UserCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'User', function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $routeParams, User) {
    $rootScope.user = User.get({ id: $routeParams.id });
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using any sever side framework for building the URL shown above?

Comment: yep. I m using asp.net mvc.
<a href="/Organization/Employee/@user.Alias#info">@user.Alias.ToUpper()</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to parse $location.absUrl() to get it.